# Delete two rows at the same time by using VBA in a given condition

Tags: vba, excel

The condition is that in `Column A`, if the cell (`A1,A2,A3....`) is a merged cell, then delete the entire row and the row above this cell

I know how to delete one entire row but I duplicate the language when trying to delete the 2nd row (can I put them together?)

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 300 Step 1
    If Cells(i, 1).MergeCells = True Then
        Rows(i - 1).EntireRow.Delete 'delete  the row above the merged cell
    End If
Next i

For i = 1 To 300 Step 1
    If Cells(i, 1).MergeCells = True Then
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete 'delete another row where the merged cell is
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 300 To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i + 1, 1).MergeCells Then Rows(i).Resize(2).EntireRow.Delete 'delete the row with the merged cell and the row above
    Next
    If Cells(1, 1).MergeCells Then Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete 'if first cell is merged, then delete its row
End Sub
```

Comment: @Baron, any feedback?

Answer (score 2):

```
For i = 1 To 300 Step 1
    If Cells(i, 1).MergeCells = True Then
        Cells(i, 1).MergeArea.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```